# Error :"The method 'toList' isn't defined for the type 'Function'. " on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

I tried to fetch data from firestore to chips using List.
The database collection name is "12words" in that collection has 2 fields, "wordName" and "categoryName". **I want to display only "wordName" field in chips.**

my code

```
class uitry5 extends StatefulWidget {
  const uitry5({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<uitry5> createState() => _uitry5State();
}

class _uitry5State extends State<uitry5> {

  List<String> wordList = [];
  Future<List<Words12>> fetchRecords() async {
    var records = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('12words').get();
    return mapRecords(records);
  }

  List<Words12> mapRecords(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> records) {
    var wordList = records.docs
        .map(
            (words12) {
          print(words12);
          return
            Words12(
                id: words12.id,
                wordName: words12['wordName'],
                categoryName: words12['categoryName']
            );}
            .toList();

        return wordList;
    }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(wordList);
  }

  List<String> selectedWord = [];
  List<String>? deSelectedWord = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(Config.app_background4), fit: BoxFit.fill),
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
                child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14, right: 0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: width * 0.94,
                    height: height * 0.30,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        const SizedBox(height: 16),
                        FutureBuilder<List<Words12>>(
                            future: fetchRecords(),
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                              } else {
                                List<Words12> data = snapshot.data ?? [];

                                return Wrap(
                                  children: wordList.map(
                                    (word) {
                                      bool isSelected = false;
                                      if (selectedWord!.contains(word)) {
                                        isSelected = true;
                                      }
                                      return GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          if (!selectedWord!.contains(word)) {
                                            if (selectedWord!.length < 50) {
                                              selectedWord!.add(word);
                                              deSelectedWord!.removeWhere(
                                                  (element) => element == word);
                                              setState(() {});
                                              print(selectedWord);
                                            }
                                          } else {
                                            selectedWord!.removeWhere(
                                                (element) => element == word);
                                            deSelectedWord!.add(word);
                                            setState(() {
                                              // selectedHobby.remove(hobby);
                                            });
                                            print(selectedWord);
                                            print(deSelectedWord);
                                          }
                                        },
                                        child: Container(
                                          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              horizontal: 5, vertical: 4),
                                          child: Container(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                vertical: 5, horizontal: 12),
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: isSelected
                                                    ? HexColor('#0000FF')
                                                    : HexColor('#D9D9D9'),
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(18),
                                                border: Border.all(
                                                    color: isSelected
                                                        ? HexColor('#0000FF')
                                                        : HexColor('#D9D9D9'),
                                                    width: 2)),
                                            child: Text(
                                              word,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: isSelected
                                                      ? Colors.black
                                                      : Colors.black,
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ).toList(),
                                );
                              }
                            }),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'dart:convert';

Words12 words12FromJson(String str) => Words12.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String words12ToJson(Words12 data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Words12 {
  Words12({
    required this.id,
    required this.wordName,
    required this.categoryName,
  });
  String id;
  String wordName;
  String categoryName;

  factory Words12.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Words12(
        id: json["id"],
        wordName: json["wordName"],
        categoryName: json["categoryName"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "wordName": wordName,
        "categoryName": categoryName,
      };
}
```

Images of errors

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zT3RdLeT2wnuyP0OmBIOnMil_4g0My2B?usp=sharing

And for fetch on the UI, I don't have an idea how to display only "wordName" filed from the collection.

As I think errors also has here.

```
return Wrap(
                                  children: wordList.map(
                                    (word) {
                                      bool isSelected = false;
                                      if (selectedWord!.contains(word)) {
                                        isSelected = true;
                                      }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing `)` on map.

```dart
  List<Words12> mapRecords(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> records) {
    var wordList = records.docs.map((words12) {
      print(words12);
      return ...;
    }).toList(); //here 

    return wordList;
  }
```

As For next issue try,

```dart
  List<Words12> mapRecords(QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> records) {
    var wordList = records.docs
        .map((words12) => Words12.fromJson(words12.data()))
        .toList();
    return wordList;
  }
```

For null issue on model class

```dart
factory Words12.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Words12(
      id: json["id"]?? "got null",
      wordName: json["wordName"]?? "got null",
      categoryName: json["categoryName"]?? "got null",
    );
```

You can find more about

- [reading firestore data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)
- [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: Now error was resolved but on the console show  this ...

Comment: I/flutter (17828): Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'
I/flutter (17828): Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'
I/flutter (17828): Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'
I/flutter (17828): Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'
I/flutter (17828): Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'
I/flutter (17828): Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'

Comment: sorry I didn't get it

Comment: `records.docs.map((words12) => Words12.fromJson(words12.data())).toList()`

Comment: Bro ,Then display Error:type'Null' is not a subtype of type'String' And I want display only  "wrodName" field . In the collection has 2 field as "wordName" and "CategoryName"

Comment: This  issue is with your model class.

Comment: I tried that but now also nothing display. And on the console display empty array "I/flutter (17828): []". I think can't display only "wordName" and also  Warp widget.I don't have an idea about that. If you have please help me that's biggest help to me.

Comment: It could be issue with your query, check `reading firestore data` link about query